# What is the Ninject syntax for registration and getting FluentValidations IValidator

Tags: ninject, fluentvalidation, ninject-2

I am using fody.validar and it's work very well but I would like to use Ninject as the ValidationFactory instead of the home made one. Because I need to inject some services to validate things outside the context of the object being validated.

Can someone help me rewrite this:

```
public static class ValidationFactory
{
    static readonly Dictionary<RuntimeTypeHandle, IValidator> Validators = new Dictionary<RuntimeTypeHandle, IValidator>();

    public static IValidator GetValidator(Type modelType)
    {
        IValidator validator;
        if (!Validators.TryGetValue(modelType.TypeHandle, out validator))
        {
            var typeName = modelType.Name + "Validator";
            var type = Type.GetType("Nexcom.KnownTypes.PropertyFields.Validation." + typeName, true);
            validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            Debug.Assert(validator != null);
            Validators.Add(modelType.TypeHandle, validator);
        }
        return validator;
    }
}
```

To use Ninject instead?

I found this code

```
public class FluentValidatorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        AssemblyScanner
            .FindValidatorsInAssemblyContaining<TextBoxValidator>()
            .ForEach(match => Bind(match.InterfaceType).To(match.ValidatorType));
    }
}
```

And hooked it up like this:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new FluentValidatorModule());
```

But I don't know how to bind it all together.

Here is one of the validators I want to bind to a PropertyField:

```
public class BasePropertyFieldValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> where T: IPropertyField
{
    [Inject] private IUniquePropertyName _uniqueProperty;

    public BasePropertyFieldValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(c => c.Name)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Please specify a name")
            .Matches(UniquePropertyName.ValidNameRegex)
            .WithMessage("Name can only contain: a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _")
            .Must(_uniqueProperty.NameIsUnique)
            .WithMessage("Please enter a unique name");
    }
}
```

Comment: You using Ninject 1, 2 or 3? If not 3, get onto the NuGet versions ASAP

Answer (score 0):

The `Bind`ing bit seems OK, assuming it compiles. (Guessing now.. you may need to port the `AssemblyScanner` bit to `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions` but you haven't told us anything about that.)

The main thing you're doing wrong is injecting a `private` field. As the wiki says, in V2, fields don't get injected (pretty sure privates don't either).

You also haven't shown where / how the `BasePropertyFieldValidator` class is being consumed and/or what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank's for taking the time to look at my code. I Think what I really would like to know is this:
How do I register all validators and how do I get a Validator for a given type.
I guess this is Ioc for beginners (-:

Comment: @MartinAndersen Well, the `FluentValidatorModule` [assuming it is supported directly in V3] is doing the right sort of thing (and if not, a quick peek at the Conventions wiki should set you on your way. Re how you use it, I don't know - what sort of code are you writing - who is using these classes? You can wait until someone that is *really* bored to go look at your cited library or you can show in the small the ways in which it touches your code and/or the container.